# Linux: TRULY uninstall package?

Tags: linux, uninstallation, linux-mint

I have installed Skype on Linux Mint 17. I was asked to select a language. I was asked to agree to something. Now I uninstall via "sudo apt-get --purge autoremove skype" (as according to my google searches). Then I reinstall via "sudo apt-get install skype". No language selection, no agreement, I immediately get logged into my account, do not even need to type the password. That's not a true uninstall ... ?

Comment: This question does not belong to stack overflow

Comment: 1. this is a SuperUser question; 2. look for `.skype` in your home directory

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get autoremove` removes packages that were installed automatically as a result of you choosing to install packages that you no longer have on your system. It won't remove packages you specifically chose to install. You were probably thinking of `apt-get remove`, which uninstalls a package.

`--purge` is also not a flag. You want to use `apt-get purge`, which will remove any package and it's configuration.

See [the man pages for `apt-get` for more](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-get).

Comment: I answered this without thinking, but I've voted to close, this is definitely off-topic for StackOverflow and belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: No, apt-get purge is not the solution. When I reinstall it doesn't behave as it did on first install!

Comment: @user3182532 Hrm, as far as I know it should. It may be the package isn't doing the right thing. I'd suggest asking this question on Super User - it's where you will get a better response, it doesn't really belong on SO.

Answer (score 0):

From `man apt-get`:

```
purge
       purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
       purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
```

So if you want to remove Skype completely, you should type `sudo apt-get purge skype`.